# Dither pattern to detect a copy?

Tags: graphics

I am printing a document and I want to print an emblem on it that will be copy resistant.

For example, let's say I print the document using a 600 dpi printer. Someone copies the document on a photocopier that both scans and prints at 600 dpi. What dither pattern can I use that will be most likely to make it obvious that the document has been copied?

Comment: something like physical protection with needle printer after normal printing to perforate paper with your text. Not visible at document but during scaning the points are darker - e.g. "Unauthorized copy" emerges. Do you want the similar scheme with just printed dither?

Comment: I do not think this is a computer science question. Community votes, please: offtopic?

Comment: There is no such thing as effective copy protection.